# Traits for nontype template parameter

Tags: c++

My code base has a huge number of magic integers representing entities in the solution domain.  Each has a fixed set of properties which are known at compile time.  I'd like to use traits like so:

```
const int Foo = 1234;
const int Bar = 5678;
// and so on...

template <int N> struct Traits;

template<> struct Traits<Foo>
{
    static const int val = 42;
};

template<> struct Traits<Bar>
{
    static const int val = 23;
};
// and so on...
```

I can't find any commentary on the idea in books or the web.  What bad things happen if I do this?  What is the idiomatic technique which I'm overlooking?

Comment: why do you think bad things should happen? There're good examples of traits in STL, e.g. `type_traits`

Comment: It's specifically attaching them to integer values as opposed to types.

Comment: It's completely valid to use integers as template arguments. Even inside specializations.

Comment: My only question is: why use magic numbers in the first place?  If you only need to distinguish a `Foo` from a `Bar` at compile time, why not make them e.g. empty `struct`s instead?  (And if you need to distinguish them at runtime, e.g. based on user input, then your type traits won't be useful for that.)

Comment: Good point. So it's legal but not useful & that's why I haven't seen it before.